# Application taking more than 10 secs to launch iOS13, Xcode 11.0 beta 6 version

Tags: swift4, ios13, xcode11

I am making my app compatible to iOS 13 and facing this problem with launch time that is coming to be around 15 secs for my app. I agree the code base is huge as it is a big project but still unable to figure out a way to reduce the launch time. I also have a fake splash screen that appears only for a second to display a sponsor image.

Any suggestion to how shall i proceed with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Is the time spent in your code, or in Apple's? Set a breakpoint in the first line of `func application(_ application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Comment: Also you can try Xcode menu > Product > Perform Action > Build With Timing Summary to see your build time in detail.